# jQuery functions not Working using .load() to refresh div tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm using ajax post to send my value to (uploadsignupeditadvcheck.php). After submit successfully, I need to refresh my div tag (galleryadv) to prepare for next submit. My ajax submit is successfully, but after refresh my jquery function is not working anymore. I appreciate you guys, can help on my situation. thank you.

[image]

index.php

```
<script>
    function uploadadv(){
        
          var idadv = document.getElementById("idadv").value;
          var companynameadv = document.getElementById("companynameadv").value;  
          var usernameadv = document.getElementById("usernameadv").value;        
          var aboutmeadv = $("#aboutmedecsadv").val();
          var catadv = document.getElementById("catadv").value;
          var typeadv = document.getElementById("typeadv").value;
          var keywordadv = document.getElementById("keywordadv").value;  
          var addressadv = document.getElementById("addressadv").value;    
          var countryadv = document.getElementById("countryadv").value;
          var zipadv = document.getElementById("zipadv").value;
          var stateadv = document.getElementById("stateadv").value;
          var cityadv = document.getElementById("cityadv").value; 
          var urladv = document.getElementById("urladv").value; 
          var priceadv = document.getElementById("priceadv").value; 
          var advstamp = document.getElementById("advstamp").value; 
        
        
        var myData = 'idadv='+idadv+ '&companynameadv='+companynameadv+ '&usernameadv='+ usernameadv+ '&aboutmeadv='+aboutmeadv+ '&catadv='+catadv+ '&typeadv='+typeadv+ '&keywordadv='+ keywordadv+ '&addressadv='+ addressadv+ '&countryadv='+ countryadv+ '&zipadv='+ zipadv+ '&stateadv='+ stateadv+ '&cityadv='+ cityadv+ '&urladv='+ urladv+ '&priceadv='+ priceadv+ '&advstamp='+ advstamp;

        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "uploadsignupeditadvcheck.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:myData, //Form variables
        success:function(data){ 
            
           $('#messageeditcheckadv').html(data);

        },
        
        
        error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
            alert(thrownError);
        }
        });  
    };
</script> 


 <script>
                                                 
 var btn_edit = $(".avatar-galleryadv"),    
 btn_save = $(".avatar-previewgalleryadvsave");
 
 
 btn_save.hide(0);

 
 btn_edit.on("click", function() {
    $(this).hide(0);
   
    btn_save.fadeIn(300);
});

 btn_save.on("click", function() {
    $(this).hide(0);
    
    btn_edit.fadeIn(300);
 });
    
    
 </script>   



<script>  

   $( ".fa-map-marker" ).click(function() {
      $( ".navtumbler" ).toggle( "fast" );
    });  
   
</script> 




 <div class="galleryadv">               

    <div class="avatar-galleryadv">
                                 
       <div class="avatar-editgalleryadv">
             <input type='file' id="uploadFileadv" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />
             <label for="imageadv"></label>
       </div>
                                       
       <div class="avatar-previewgalleryadv">
             <div id="imagePreviewgalleryadv" style="background-image: url(images/whitecamera.png); background-color:#181818; background-size:contain; background-repeat:no-repeat;"> 
             </div> 
       </div>

    </div>
                  


    <div class="avatar-previewgalleryadvsave">
       <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true" id="uploadimageadv" style="margin:1px 0px 0px 0.4px;"></i>
    </div>


    <div class="igVideoData" style="color:#FFF; float:left;">
                                                             
     
     <i class="fa fa-map-marker spriteTemplate" aria-hidden="true" ></i> 
                                         
                                                  
    </div>  

</div>
```

uploadsignupeditadvcheck.php

```
$(".galleryadv").load(location.href+" .galleryadv>*");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting dom elements that event handlers were attached to before. So you attach click events to buttons first, and then you load fresh HTML and overwriting the  buttons that had handlers attached to so the new buttons have no event handlers attached to, that is why they do not respond to click events.

Either attach event handler to parent element that does not get overwritten, or reattach event handlers after you load and overwrite with new html.

I would probably go with attaching events to their parent, so it gets handled when event propagate up the dom tree.

```
var buttons_parent = $('.galleryadv');

buttons_parent.on('click', '.avatar-galleryadv', function(){    
    $(this).hide(0);   
    $('.avatar-previewgalleryadvsave').fadeIn(300);
});

buttons_parent.on('click', '.avatar-previewgalleryadvsave', function(){
    $(this).hide(0);   
    $('.avatar-galleryadv').fadeIn(300);
});
```

And this goes instead of `btn_edit.on("click", function() {...` and  `btn_save.on("click", function() {...`. Also I don't refer to buttons inside handlers by their reference saved in the variables because these will be invalid after overwriting them so I always look for them by their class names.

This way even when buttons are overwriten the handlers that handles their click events are intact.

Comment: thank you for helping me to solved this problem Mr_KoKa. really appreciate

Comment: But now my customized selection tag always change to default selection tag. would need some help to resolve my customized selection tag background colour, it changes back to the default colour instead of black whenever the the div refreshes, would you be able to advise on this, thanks.

Comment: I assume that by tag you mean div.galleryadv element. Does it have background color before ajax submit, or it should have that background color set only after ajax submit?

Comment: Yes my selection tag is a customized one, thanks for rely and look into my situation, is been a week plus, i have 4 problem, i use your method i solved 3 problem, but this plugin customized selection tag is not working with the above method. I have post my question but nobody reply. Pls help to look into my last problem if u can. Appreciate alot. thank you. this is my link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63033064/customized-selection-tag-background-color-not-showing-after-refresh-div-tag

Comment: Yes it has a background color before ajax submit